# Exchange-Server Query

Tags: exchange

First, a little background. I've recently been taken on as a web and software developer for a small company, who has no other in-house IT support. They've been asking my opinion on lots of IT subjects that are quite far out of my comfort zone. I'm definitely not a network admin.

Their IT consultancy contractor is pushing them to upgrade their dedicated exchange server, even though it seems like the one they currently have has a lot of life left in it and is running problem free. They say it's "coming to the natural end of it's life". They want to install a monster with a Xeon E5-2420, 32GB RAM, 2x 1TB HDDs, Windows Server 2012 and Microsoft Exchange 2010. They want to charge a small fortune for it. Basically, this system seems massively over the top seeing as it won't be doing anything else other than running as an exchange server for a company with less than 25 email accounts. My employers also have a file server system in-house that hosts three web apps, an SQL server, their local domain, print server and shared folders. That machine is using the same specs as the proposed new one, and it is barely using any of it's potential.

I asked if Microsoft Exchange 2010 could be installed on their file server, but they said that MS Exchange can't run on the same system as an SQL server because for some reason they will eat up each others resources (even though the SQL server isn't touching 1% of the current system's CPU or RAM).

My question is really, are they trying to rip my employers off? Could MS Exchange be installed on their other server (on a virtual instance or not), or does the old one even need replacing at all? Going with their current suggestion will cost the company in excess of £6k, and it seems entirely unnecessary.

I apologies, because I know this is probably a little thin on details, but if I carry on I could end up writing a massive essay that no-one will want to read. I've been doing my research, but I'm not knowledgeable enough make any hard decisions. Let me know if you need any more details.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Further Details: 
The new exchange would need to support Outlook Web App, 25 users, a few public mailboxes, and email exchange with Blackberries.

Comment: Blackberries require a Blackberry Enterprise Server to perform sync with Exchange. Exchange does not have native support for BB using EAS. Out of the box, a BB can use BB web services to connect to the Outlook Web App URL and download mail, thats it.

Comment: Honestly - for 25 users, look at hosted Exchange.

Comment: We've been quoted £180 per month hosted exchange, plus set up and migration fee. So if at all possible I think they would like to avoid that. Plus it increases the companies dependence on their IT consultancy.

Comment: Office 365 for enterprises for just the email hosting is $4US/user/month. Not sure if pricing is different internationally. So, 25 users = $100/month,$1200/year. More if you add sharepoint to replace public folders. Take your software/licensing/hardware cost plus the cost of time/maintentance/IT consultants to install/setup/maintain the solution in-house and do a 3 year comparison of total costs and see if it makes sense to you.
(Office 365 plan comparisons - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/business/compare-all-office-365-for-business-plans-FX104051403.aspx)

Comment: Hosted Exchange *decreases* your dependency on a consultant. It increases your dependency on a service provider, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL and Exchange can co-exist on the same server, that's what Small Business Server is for. (Exchange, SQL, Sharepoint, etc, all bundled together) It sounds like SBS2011 may be a good fit.

Whether or not Exchange 2010 can be installed on the current server, depends on several things. OS architecture is going to be the biggest, as Exchange 2010 is 64bit only.

If the server is running 2003, it's end of life is in 2015, while mainstream support did end in 2010.

If the company operations are running fine on the current hardware, then I would ask why the contractor is pushing it. Are there specific business needs not being met that would be satisfied with completely replacing the server?

Comment: The other server (that I proposed running the exchange on as well), is running Windows Server 2012. No specific business needs are not being met, there has been thoughts to update to better smart phones. The contractors have said that the old system (running 2003) may not exchange with newer phones/technologies etc.

Comment: Exchange 2003 will interface fine with just about any smart phone using the EAS protocol.

Comment: It sounds like the contractor is just trying to sell, honestly. Unless they are providing you a project plan, with legitimate business reasons to replace everything, then I would have them put that together. Granted, old hardware and software should be replaced, but not just for the hell of it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide enough information to determine how their suggestion matches up with the Exchange 2010 system requirements. The best thing you can do is use Microsoft's sizing calculator for Exchange 2010.

Generally speaking it is not a supported configuration to run Exchange 2010 and SQL on the same windows instance. It seems like your environment could benefit from a virtual server setup like Hyper V.

[Article on how to use the calculator](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/11/09/3408737.aspx)

[The calculator itself](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Exchange-2010-Mailbox-Server-Role-/)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look over the calculator. I've added a few extra details to the post. My rep isn't high enough to up-vote your answer, otherwise I would.

Answer (score 0):

You could look to spin up a 2012 Business Essentials to run both SQL and Exchange. Personally, I don't like the small business server windows product lines, but they do work.

You haven't given any info on the current hardware specs or the hardware specs of the other system. If the other system has enough RAM/CPU/Disk Space/IOPS/etc available, you could look at spinning up a virtual instance and run Exchange there. But, without knowing the hardware and current usage there, I can't really say one way or the other if that would work.

The specs for the new system might be a little on the high side, but they might be right on given that it will be running all the Exchange roles. I would actually look to additional (and faster) drives than the two 1TB drives.

You also don't give any info on the current exchange version and DB size. Depending on how difficult the migration from your current Exchange version would impact pricing (in terms of service hours used).

On to pricing. You have the 2 main components of pricing - hardware and services. Without knowing what your current version of Exchange is, the size of your mailbox database and without knowing the hardware/services cost breakdown and what kind of server you are getting (HP/Dell/White Box) it's hard to say if the costs are reasonable.

Taking a stab in the dark without enough info, and assuming an Exchange 2003 to 2010 migration, I would look at 3-4 days for the build and migration, decommissioning of the old Exchange environment. Included in that would be the documentation and turnover. So, 32 hours or so at their hourly rate, add to that the cost of the hardware and see if that fits with their pricing.

Given the size of your userbase, have you thought about Office 365?

Another alternative would be to add more RAM and disks to your current server and install the Hyper-V role and install Exchange into that. Again, this would depend on the current age/condition of that system and you still still need to pay for the services to install/migrate Exchange.

Comment: The hardware specs of the "other" server (our current file-server) are the same as the new proposed dedicated exchange server(this was stated in the OP). It's running on average 1% CPU usage and 10% RAM usage doing all that.

The old Exchange server is running Win Server 2003. It has 4GB RAM and a Xeon 3065 with two HDDs (1x 250 and 1x 150 GB). That server has been running that exchange for 5 years and both HDDs still have about a 3rd left on them. So the database can't be very big. I think the mailboxes total at about 100GB.

Comment: You *MIGHT* get away with a 16GB virtual guest on the existing server and leave the other 16GB for the SQL/etc. I would still look to upgrade the RAM on the current if you add a virtual machine there. I would look at the drives too (not so much capacity, but performance) to see if your current IOPS/latency on the drives will handle additional load and if you need to add additional/faster drives for the mailstores. A couple of 450GB 15k SAS aren't too much to add.